# Is DD-X developer ok to use for Acros 100?

Tags: film, darkroom, developer

Is DD-X developer ok to use for Acros 100? Also, I would like to control the contrast. Can someone point me to a development time chart that relates to the amount of contrast?

Comment: In my opinion, this is going to be opinion-based.  You could avoid that by asking instead what properties of DD-X interact in what ways with Acros (but you might also need to specify whether you mean original Acros or Acros II).

Comment: Agree w/ @ZeissIkon. Also, bear in mind that the negative is just an intermediary step to the final print. When you say "control contrast" are you trying to lower it because you shot a particularly high contrast scene? Worried about blocking your highlights? What are you going for? Also, will you be scanning or printing in the darkroom?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I might go either way with the contrast. Some times less and sometimes more. Maybe it doesn't matter since I will be scaning to digital. I might try my hand at pushing film just to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

It should be (more than) fine, yes. [Massive Dev Chart](https://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php?Film=Fuji+Neopan+100+Acros&Developer=%25Ilfotec+DD%25&mdc=Search&TempUnits=C&TimeUnits=T) and [FilmDev](https://filmdev.org/film/show/1016?developer_id=1014) both have some suggestions for this particular combination (the latter with sample photos). Plus, there's a lot of discussion on various forums, if you google "acros in dd-x".

As for control of contrast, you could try to extrapolate from the [Acros data sheet](https://www.fujifilmusa.com/shared/bin/NeopanAcros100.pdf), which gives characteristic curves for various developers (though ultimately you'd have to run your own tests to find out how the film behaves in DD-X). Looking at the G-bar-against-time plot in section 14 of that document, a reasonable first guess would be to expect an increase of 0.1 in G-bar for every added 2 minutes of development time (in 20°C).